# Filter in CollabMobile?

Tags: android, ios

Anybody knows about CollabMobile(www.collabmobile.com) nice tool to visualize your data for mobile devices with native chart components like roambi. 
I could bind my sql server easily but is there anybody knows how to add a combobox filtering the grid component on the screen for tablet or phone?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new datatable for combobox. At the screen design section, set datatable property of combobox. After that use ; **Filtered Table**, **Filtered Column** and **Filtered Type** properties to use combobox as a filter to your other components. Basicly just select the **datatable and related column/field** of your component that you'd like to be filtered by the combobox selection. That's it.

**Don't forget to check related screen elements after you change existing datatable.** Name or index changes in datatables may cause a blank screen on a report.